# MonoDevelop editor GUI designer

Tags: c#, user-interface, monodevelop, gtk#, gui-designer

I just downloaded the MonoDevelop source code from their website. Now I want to change some of the GUI elements of the IDE. After a bit of research I found out that monodevelop's gui is made with GTK#. But I can't find a visual designer to open the source files and edit the gui. I have tried Glade (which cannot open the source files), and MonoDevelop's Stetic GUI Designer (but that one doesn't show a designer window).

So is there a GUI designer to (re)design the windows and components in monodevelop?

Comment: Wonder if it eats its own dog food. Did you try opening it up in an instance of itself?

Comment: Yes I did. It gives a few errors at first, but then you can view and change the source code. Unfortunately I cannot open a gui designer :(

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which parts of the GUI in MonoDevelop you are interested in changing.

A lot of the dialogs and widgets are written in GTK# using MonoDevelop's Stetic GUI designer. You can usually tell which projects have GUI elements use the Stetic GUI designer since they have a gtk-gui directory with some generated files.

If you have the GTK# Visual Designer addin enabled in MonoDevelop you should see a User Interface folder in the Solution window. You should be able to open one of these files into the GTK# designer by double clicking them, or by right clicking and selecting Open.

In the screenshot below I have opened the FindInFilesDialog.

[image: MonoDevelop GTK# designer]

Some GUI parts are written in XWT, which does not have a designer. Other GUI parts are written by hand without any GUI designer and will not be able to be loaded by the GTK# designer since it expects a certain set of files to be available in the project.